# sql server : handle null table type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-types

I am passing a null table type in sql procedure and getting error **Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with MyFilters**, how can we solve it, TIA.

**Proc :-**

```
Create procedure [dbo].[Filters]
(
@MyFilters dbo.MyFilters READONLY,
@UserId int=0
)
as
begin   
-- code..
end
```

**Type :-**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyFilters] AS TABLE(
ColumnName varchar(30),
FirstFilterType varchar(20),
FirstFilterVal varchar(200),
SecondFilterType varchar(20),
SecondFilterVal varchar(200),
MultiOperator varchar(10),
IsMulti bit,
ColumnType varchar(20)
)
```

Comment: Show us the code of creating `dbo.MyFilters`

Comment: Include the T-SQL implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

Table type cannot be null, but it can be empty(without any rows)
You can simple exec your sp without parameters: `EXEC [dbo].[Filters]` and @MyFilters will be empty